# Why do they ask whether it is a paycheck or not in a bank?

Tags: canada, banking, check

I am getting paid with checks so each time I deposit it to my bank account they ask whether it is a paycheck or not. What difference does it make?

Comment: Who asks?  Your bank?  Is it a pretty large transaction?  Is it a hand written check or a computer printed check?

Comment: Suggestion: Ask them :P

Comment: @MrChrister bank teller is the one who asks, checks are hand written, and transactions are not that big, unfortunately :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Some banks waive the normal holds for check clearance for paychecks.

Comment: that's probably it...

Comment: so the answer is "yes"

Answer (score 6):

It's all about risk management.

Paychecks are less likely to bounce.